# Is there a way to export an object while preserving variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, import

So say I have one file (file1.js) with the following code:

```js
var output = {
  thing: "A thing",
  another: "Another thing"
}
```

Now if I were to reference this in another file, like this:

```html
<script src='file1.js'></script>
<script>
console.log(output);//Logs the object to the console.
</script>
```

it would import the `output` variable, for use. However if I were to use exports, as in the following snippet it would *not* work, and instead only allow imports:

```js
//file1.js
var output = {
  thing: "A thing",
  another: "Another thing"
}
export default output;
```

```html
<script type="module">
   import something from "file1.js";
   console.log(something.thing);//"A thing";
   console.log(output);//Error, but if I had omitted the exports and imports it would work fine.
</script>
```

Is there a way to make *both* of these work? So that I could `import something from "file1.js"` while still being able to use the "output" variable? Note that I'm using this in a library so I cannot rely on the user to do something client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *possible*, but I wouldn't recommend it in most cases: assign the exported object to the window first:

```
const output = {
  thing: "A thing",
  another: "Another thing"
};
window.output = output;
export default output;
```

Then you'll be able to use both `window.output` and the imported object.

But one of the main benefits of using modules is *constrained scope* and avoiding unnecessary global pollution, which is kind of defeated by explicitly polluting the global object.

It could make sense if this is done in only *one* place - like to assigning the whole library namespace to a single property on the window - but I'd hope not to see relying on global properties to be frequently relied on.

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! =) I'm only doing this for one variable and I don't want the user to have to use imports, but I want that to be an option.

Comment: it works fine when using import but when just doing script:src it does not work.

Comment: Scripts with `import` / `export` syntax must be modules. You must use `<script type="module" src="...">`. Even if the script consuming this one is not using `import` to take in the `output` variable, your library still needs to have `type="module"` on the HTML page. Either that, or make two separate versions of your library: one with ES6 modules, and one that assigns itself to the `window`.